# Поиск и замена текста в файле

Tags: python, python-3.x

В файле есть текст который нужно найти и заменить.

Пример: ищем - `textsearch="123"`. Проблема в том, что данные в кавычках "" всегда разные.

Как найти `textsearch="123"` игнорируя данные в кавычках и заменить?

Делал замену так:

```
filedata = filedata.replace('textsearch="123"', 'changetext')
```

Comment: Регулярным выражением `textsearch="(.*?)"`

Comment: в след раз. представляйте пример входного файла и фрагмент кода, что бы участники форума могли протестировать и быстрее представить Вам ответ.